# sensor_msgs::CvBridge or cv_bridge in hydro

Tags: sensor-msgs, ros-hydro, cv-bridge, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

During adaptation from Electric to Hydro, I find that sensor_msgs::CvBridge is gone. Using cv_bridge doesn't work either. Looking through the wiki doesn't really help much. Any clue on how to get on ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172101/sensor_msgs::cvbridge-or-cv_bridge-in-hydro/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a complete answer, but this tutorial is up to date for the latest version of cv_bridge: http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-06-02**:
Thank you. Despite this tutorial and looking around I get compatibility issues like that cvToImgMsg is no member of cv_bridge. I assume that I have to re-code everything concerning cv_bridge and sensor_msgs.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-02**:
It looks like cvToImgMsg is now toImageMsg and is a function on the CvImage class, rather than being a standalone function. Bottom line is, you'll probably have to rewrite most of your image conversions.